# Catch string between tags with nom delimited

Tags: rust, nom

I'm trying to learn to use nom (5.0.1) and want to get the string between two tags:

```
use nom::{
    bytes::complete::{tag_no_case, take_while},
    character::{is_alphanumeric},
    error::{ParseError},
    sequence::{delimited},
    IResult,
};

fn root<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &str, E> {
    delimited(
        tag_no_case("START;"),
        take_while(is_alphanumeric),
        tag_no_case("END;"),
    )(i)
}
```

But this gives me the error

```
error[E0271]: type mismatch resolving `<&str as nom::InputTakeAtPosition>::Item == u8`
   --> src/main.rs:128:9
    |
128 |         take_while(is_alphanumeric),
    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^ expected char, found u8
```

What have I done wrong here? I'm fairly new to Rust and a total beginner with nom so I'm expecting it to be something really obvious in the end :)

Comment: Please include the imports so we know exactly where each function is coming from. `nom` has multiple functions named `take_while`, and I can't find `is_alphanumeric` in the doc.

Comment: I've added the imports now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `is_alphanumeric` from `nom` expects a parameter of type `u8`, but you give it a `char`. Use `is_alphanumeric` from `std` instead:

```rust
fn root<'a, E: ParseError<&'a str>>(i: &'a str) -> IResult<&'a str, &str, E> {
    delimited(
        tag_no_case("START;"),
        take_while(char::is_alphanumeric),
        tag_no_case("END;"),
    )(i)
}
```

Comment: Don't cast a `char` to an `u8`, it will overflow if it's a codepoint greater than 255. eg: `println!("{}", '፡' as u8 as char);` prints `a`

Comment: I tried `take_while(char::is_alphanumeric)` which gives the same result as your closure suggestion. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I don't have all the info needed (exact type of `take_while` and `is_alphanumeric`), so I'll try to approximate one.

---

As you want `take_while(F)(i)` to returns `&str` (ie. almost `&[char]`), then `take_while(F)` must have type `impl Fn(&[char]) -> IResult<&[char], &[char], Error>`.

However, `take_while` takes an argument of type `Fn(<Input as InputTakeAtPosition>::Item) -> bool`, and returns `impl Fn(Input) -> IResult<Input, Input, Error>`.

So, this means `F` the argument to `take_while` must have type `Fn(&[char]) -> IResult<&[char], &[char], Error>`

Does your `is_alphanumeric` have this type, or is it `Fn(&[u8]) -> IResult<&[u8], &[u8], Error>`?

---

Or it could be the opposite, you may have a `take_while` that works on `&[u8]`, which doesn't work with your function that takes and returns `&str` (which, again, is mostly a `&[char]`, and absolutely not a `&[u8]`)